# Has Swift compilation condition for SwiftUI preview environment?

Tags: swift, swiftui, conditional-compilation

`Objective C` has preprocessor, `Swift` has compilation conditions that allows to use different code for different environments, for example for debug or release build:

```swift
#if DEBUG
    print("debug message")
    doDebugAction()
#else
    doReleaseAction()
#endif
```

Can I add code that compiles only for SwiftUI preview? Something like:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(swiftUIPreview) 
    static func mock() -> SomeStruct {
        // fill random data
    } 
#endif
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check if SwiftUI is in preview mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759987/how-do-you-check-if-swiftui-is-in-preview-mode)

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately it doesn't exist any compilation condition afaik, but you can use `ProcessInfo`:

```swift
ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] == "1"
```